# React Query Test with MSW - renderHook result always returns null

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query, msw

I am trying to test my react query hook using msw but `renderHook`'s `result`'s `current` value is always null. Why?

**Note**: the reason `fetch` does not include a URL is because this is a Rails Propshaft app and React and Rails apps share the same port.

In the real app, everything works and the hook returns data just fine but not in the test.

[tutorial I followed](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/testing-react-query)

[reproducible sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-dewdney-r6k4mm?file=/src/App.spec.tsx)

**App.spec.tsx**

```
const testQueryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: false
    }
  }
});

testQueryClient.setQueryDefaults(["accounts"], { retry: 5 });

describe("Accounts", () => {
  it("renders accounts", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFetchAccounts(), {
      wrapper: () => (
        <QueryClientProvider client={testQueryClient}>
          <App />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      )
    });

    console.log("result", result);
    await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBe(true));
  });
});
```

**hooks.tsx**

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

type FormattedAccount = {
  id: number;
  label: string;
};

const fetchAccount = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("/api/accounts");
  const accounts = await res.json();

  console.log("accounts", accounts);
  const formattedAccounts: FormattedAccount[] = [...accounts]?.map(
    (option) => ({
      id: option.id,
      label: option.name,
    })
  );

  console.log("formattedAccounts", formattedAccounts);
  return formattedAccounts;
};

export const useFetchAccounts = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["accounts"],
    queryFn: () => fetchAccount()
  });
};
```

**server.ts**

```
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { rest } from "msw";

export const handlers = [
  rest.get("/api/accounts", (req, res, ctx) => {
    const rres = res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json([{ id: 1, name: "Account 1" }]));
    console.log("rres", rres);
    return rres;
  })
];

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
```

**jest.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */

module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.spec.{ts, tsx}"],
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest"
  }
};
```

**jest.setup.ts**

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import "whatwg-fetch";
import { server } from "./server";

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

export default global.matchMedia =
  global.matchMedia ||
  function (query) {
    return {
      matches: false,
      media: query,
      onchange: null,
      addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
      addEventListener: jest.fn(),
      removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
    };
  };
```

Comment: Try running in debug mode to see if the requests are being caught

https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/debugging-uncaught-requests#run-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 0):

It could be that MSW is intercepting the complete path and is unable to match this with the handler you have for "/api/accounts"

You can test this by changing:

```
rest.get("/api/accounts", (req, res, ctx)
```

to:

```
rest.get("*/api/accounts", (req, res, ctx)
```

Note how I've added an asterisk wildcard to match all base paths (more info on using regular expressions in the request matching [here](https://mswjs.io/docs/basics/request-matching#request-url)). I couldn't verify this suggestion in your sandbox as it was not working for me.